# destructuring inside a reduce method

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, reduce, destructuring

I would like to know if it´s possible to destructuring directly inside a reduce method on JS. I´m trying to do something like this:

With this 2D array:

```
currency = [
    ["PENNY", 0.01],
    ["NICKEL", 0.05],
    ["DIME", 0.01],
    ["QUARTER", 0.25],
    ["ONE", 1],
    ["FIVE", 5],
    ["TEN", 10],
    ["TWENTY", 20],
    ["ONE HUNDRED", 100]
];
```

I would like to get the sum of all amounts. I mean something like this:

```
const [curr, amount] = change;

return change.reduce(amount => amount + b);
```

Even better would be destructuring the currency array directly inside the reduce method´s callback.

Comment: Consider putting the destructure inside an array map?

Comment: Uh, yeah, you have to put the code inside the callback if that's where you want to run it, and where presumably the `change` variable was available.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to sum the amounts:

```
const sum = currency.reduce((total, [_, amount]) => total + amount, 0);
```

Each sub-array is destructured into the denomination name and amount.

Comment: Or even: `const sum = currency.reduce((total, [, amount]) => total + amount);`, almost the same but without initial value, and just omit first element from array without `_`

Comment: @Kyr sure, that always looks weird to me but that's my personal issue :)

Comment: agree, a little bit, but better then warning "Unused variable _"

Comment: I get the habit of using `_` from Erlang, which explicitly supports "I'm not going to use this" variable names.

Answer (score 0):

There are many variants. Without changing structure of data i this:

```
return currency.map(element => element[1]).reduce((acc, curr) => acc + curr);
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
let currency = [
    ["PENNY", 0.01],
    ["NICKEL", 0.05],
    ["DIME", 0.01],
    ["QUARTER", 0.25],
    ["ONE", 1],
    ["FIVE", 5],
    ["TEN", 10],
    ["TWENTY", 20],
    ["ONE HUNDRED", 100]
];
console.log(currency.reduce((acc, cur) => {return acc + cur[1]},0))
```